# populate values in to two textboxes from a single userform

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a code in Ms-Word vba.

I made two userform say **userform_1** and **userform_2**

- **userform_1** contains two buttons and two textboxes.
- **userform_2** is a calendar userform.

I wrote a code for showing a calendar useform on each button click event.

Now, I want to write a code such that when user clicks on 1st button the selected calendar values will display in textbox1 and when user clicks on 2nd button the selected value displayed in the 2nd textbox. But it displays the same value in textboxes.

Please let me know this how could i achieve this...

```
Private Sub CmB_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    Main.Event_DblClick = True
    Dim SampleDate As Date
    frmAE_Tool.TextBox1.Text = Me.Value
    frmAE_Tool.TextBox2.Text = Me.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create a `Sub` in your **userform_2** which going to determine the output of the calendar.

---

#### Userform_2 :

**Declare a `Private` variable like below :**

```
Private mTextBox As Control
```

(*This textbox would be the output textbox of your calendar*)

**Add the following `Sub` :**

```
Public Sub SetOutput(pTextBox As Control)
    Set mTextBox = pTextBox
End Sub
```

(*This Sub would allow to decide which output you want to use*)

**Modify your `CmB_DblClick Sub` like this :**

```
Private Sub CmB_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'Others things that I didn't understand

    mToolbox = Me.Value
End Sub
```

---

#### Userform_1 :

For the first button, modify the `Click Sub` like this :

```
Private Sub Btn1_Click
    [...]
    YourCalendarForm.SetOutput Textbox1
End Sub
```

And for the second, like this :

```
Private Sub Btn2_Click
    [...]
    YourCalendarForm.SetOutput Textbox2
End Sub
```